# Concatenate search query and preset text to a search

Tags: javascript, html, search, bing

Trying to re-create this search url
https://www.bing.com/search?q=site:https://www.imdb.com/title+Hakunamatata

but this code keeps doing the wrong thing. I want to concatenate the URL's. Not start a second query inline

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.bing.com/search">
    <input type="text" name="q" size="25" maxlength="255" value="Hakunamatata" />
    <input type="hidden" name="q1" value="site:www.imdb.com/title" />
    <input type="submit" value="Bing Search" />
</form>
```

What I keep getting is URL's with & in them instead of +.
Is there some kind of Javascript or something that can combine the search terms into one search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use JavaScript to prepend `'site:www.imdb.com/title '` to the input's value when the `submit` event is fired.

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', function(){
  query.value = 'site:www.imdb.com/title ' + query.value;
})
```

```html
<form method="get" action="http://www.bing.com/search" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="q" size="25" maxlength="255" value="Hakunamatata" id="query"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Bing Search" />
</form>
```

Comment: 5 hours of trying javascript snippets and you give me the answer in like 20 minutes... I love this site! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Your result worked perfect for when I had a single form button, however it does not seem to function when I add two buttons. I made a new question since you already accurately answered the current question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70115900/appending-text-to-results-of-html-form-action-search-one-text-box-2-buttons-2

Answer (score 0):

So, I had a brother rebuild the script in JS since I needed some complicated formatting tweaks. This is the end result

```js
    function submitForm(elm, url, values, query) {
        let baseLoc = new URL(url);
        let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(baseLoc.search);
        for (const key in values) {
            let inputBox = elm.parentElement.querySelector(
                `input[name="${values[key]}"]`
            );
            searchParams.set(key, inputBox.value);
        }
        for (const key in query) {
            searchParams.set(key, query[key]);
        }
        let newTab = window.open(`${url}?${searchParams.toString()}`);
        if (!newTab)
            alert(
                'Pop-up Blocker is enabled! Please add this site to your exception list.'
            );
    }
```

```html
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault();">
    <input type="text" value="" name="inputBox" />
    <input type="text" value="" name="inputBox2" /><br />
    <button
        onclick="submitForm(this, 'https:/\/bing.com/search/',{'q':'inputBox'},{'test':'fish','123':'lookup'});"
        class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
    >
        btn2
    </button>
    <button
        onclick="submitForm(this, 'https:/\/ebay.com/sch/',{'_nkw':'inputBox2'},{'asd':'123'});"
        class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
    >
        btn2
    </button>
</form>
```

Optionally, use this if you want to have a button that submits all buttons at once.

```js
    function submitAllButtons(elm) {
        let allButtons = elm.parentElement.querySelectorAll('button');
        console.log(allButtons);
        for (const button of allButtons) {
            if (elm != button) button.click();
        }
    }
```

```html
    <button onclick="submitAllButtons(this)" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">
        ALL
    </button>
```