# Appending text to results of HTML form action search, one text box, 2 buttons, 2 possible results,

Tags: javascript, html, forms, get, bing

I used @John Strood's answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873005/html-form-action-search-one-text-box-2-buttons-2-possible-results) to build my current script. The below code is close to my need, I now just need to append text to the results.

For example, appending `site:imdb.com/title` to`Hakunamatata` to get `https://www.bing.com/search?q=site:imdb.com/title+Hakunamatata`

[@Spectric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70105653/concatenate-search-query-and-preset-text-to-a-search) had a great answer for a single-submit form, but it does not seem to function with the current script.

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" value="Hakunamatata"  id="box" name="search_query"placeholder="text" autofocus />

    <input type="submit" value="BNG" formaction="https://testurl1.com"
        onclick="document.getElementById('box').name='q'" />

    <input type="submit" value="ABB" formaction="http://testurl2.com"
        onclick="document.getElementById('box').name='s'" />
</form>
```

If you are wondering, the onclick functions are necessary
`testurl1` uses the search modifier of `?q` and `testurl2` uses `?s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepend the string to the input's value when the `submit` event is fired.

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', function() {
  box.value = 'site:imdb.com/title ' + box.value;
})
```

```html
<form action="" method="get" id="form">
  <input type="text" value="Hakunamatata" id="box" name="search_query" placeholder="text" autofocus />

  <input type="submit" value="BNG" formaction="http://www.bing.com/search" onclick="document.getElementById('box').name='q'" />

  <input type="submit" value="ABB" formaction="http://www.bing.com/search" onclick="document.getElementById('box').name='s'" />
</form>
```

To conditionally prepend the string, move the logic to the button's `click` event listener.

```html
<form action="" method="get" id="form">
  <input type="text" value="Hakunamatata" id="box" name="search_query" placeholder="text" autofocus />

  <input type="submit" value="BNG" formaction="http://www.bing.com/search" onclick="document.getElementById('box').name='q';box.value = 'site:imdb.com/title ' + box.value;" />

  <input type="submit" value="ABB" formaction="http://www.bing.com/search" onclick="document.getElementById('box').name='s'" />
</form>
```

Comment: You my good sir, are amazing! Thank you so much! One final question, is there a way to make the append function, only effect specific buttons? For example append the text to the first submit function but not the second or subsequent?

Comment: @SuperMar1o Yes. I've updated my answer to show how 

Comment: you are amazing. You do not realize how much of a help you are. Believe it or not, there is nowhere else on the internet I can find, where these functions, working together, are in one place. It's been 2 days of searching lol. I finally gave up and had to ask (not great at JS). Thank you again! You are amazing!

Comment: Final question, I promise. Is there a way to make this function with target="blank" To open it a new tab. Seems with onclick, target-blank oes not work. I tried adding "window.open('code.here', '_blank)'" but it seems to not that simple.

Comment: @SuperMar1o Add `target="_blank"` to the form or `formtarget="_blank"` to the input.

Comment: Had to run to a thanksgiving thing, just got back. Worked perfectly! Thanks again!